# How to write os awareness t32 config for test OS

Tags: lauterbach

Currently writing custom OS so for debugging need to know whether we need to check with t32 lauterbach for writing OS awareness module or there is any open documentation available for same

Can debug our OS with t32

Answer (score 0):

For writing your own OS awareness you need a development kit which is provided by Lauterbach under NDA. Please contact Lauterbach (https://www.lauterbach.com).